# Simulate installation of package in R

Tags: r, installation, package

Is there a way from within R to simulate the installation of a package, without actually installing it?

---

If you know Debian or Ubuntu, what I have in mind is something like the `-s` parameter of `apt-get` there.

Comment: Can you please explain why and what does `apt-get -s` do?

Comment: It simulates the installation of a package, without actually installing it. It checks the dependencies, the compatibility with other packages, the writability of the folders, the conflicts, and so on. Basically everything that it would need to do when installing, but without actually writing anything on the disk.

Comment: Download the tarball and run `devtools::check`, or use `R CMD CHECK` in, e.g. `/tmp`, as this is pretty much what `devtools::check` does.

Comment: `R CMD INSTALL --library=/tmp pkg` perhaps adding `--debug` if you are doing this to get the most feedback on the install process.

Comment: @nrussel I guess I should use `download.file()`, right? How do I know the path of the file to be downloaded?

Comment: More conveniently, `download.packages("some_package", destdir = "/tmp", type = "source")`.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `devtools::load_all()`

Comment: I am not really good with R, I am definitely a beginner. I am following tutorials and courses, and I would prefer to go on a safe road and check the consistency of my system everytime that somebody suggests me to install anything, before doing it and risking breaking everything (some packages write their configurations in my home and such). Obviously the second would be better, but I guess that it is not doable, right?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do something like this on Linux is to create ramdisk. You'll simulate whole installation, it is very fast, and it will be gone as soon as you reboot/unmount ramdisk. Along the lines

```
> sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=512m tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk
```

or add line to /etc/fstab

```
> tmpfs       /mnt/ramdisk tmpfs   nodev,nosuid,noexec,nodiratime,size=512M   0 0
```

and then as suggested

```
> R CMD INSTALL --library=/mnt/ramdisk pkg_name
```

or other installation tests as desired

Comment: This look like a great suggestion, but unfortunately I do not have root access on the machine (office policy).

Comment: @dadexix86 you could probably ask to add `fstab` entry with flag `user` stated. Then you as non-privileged user could mount ramdisk. Talk to your sysadmin